# How can I turn off WP_DEBUG_LOG messages coming from a specific plugin or theme?

Tags: debug

This is a seemingly simple question... I was wondering if anyone knows how to turn off `WP_DEBUG_LOG` messages coming from a specific plugin or theme?

This assumes `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);` in `wp-config.php` but its a global definition...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably annoyed by too many DEBUG messages of unrelated plugins. The best solution I found for this was to turn on DEBUG logging only if a certain URL is matched:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], 'page=myplugin') !== false)
   define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
else
   define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', false);
```